# sql server 2008 Incorrect syntax near ','. error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is the query which is to create table in sql

```
create table Staging (
d_name varchar(250), town_name varchar(250),
farmer_name_F varchar(250) ,farmer_name_L varchar(250) ,
father_name_F varchar(250),father_name_L varchar(250),
area integer, crop_type varchar(220), sow_date DATE,
visit_date DATE, pest_pop_1 double, 
pest_pop_2 double, pest_pop_3 double,
pest_pop_4 double, pest_pop_5 double,
pest_pop_6 double, pest_pop_7 double,
pest_pop_8 double, pest_pop_9 double,
pest_pop_10 double, pest_pop_11 double,
pest_pop_12 double, pesticide varchar(230),
spray_date DATE, dosage double,
dosage_cor varchar(230), disease double, 
disease_cor varchar(226), height double, height_cor varchar(230)
)
```

but the problem is it give me error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Incorrect syntax near ','.
```

kindly solve my problem thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `double` with `float` as this is the data type for SQL Server

```
create table Staging (
d_name varchar(250), town_name varchar(250),
farmer_name_F varchar(250) ,farmer_name_L varchar(250) ,
father_name_F varchar(250),father_name_L varchar(250),
area integer, crop_type varchar(220), sow_date DATE,
visit_date DATE, pest_pop_1 float, 
pest_pop_2 float, pest_pop_3 float,
pest_pop_4 float, pest_pop_5 float,
pest_pop_6 float, pest_pop_7 float,
pest_pop_8 float, pest_pop_9 float,
pest_pop_10 float, pest_pop_11 float,
pest_pop_12 float, pesticide varchar(230),
spray_date DATE, dosage float,
dosage_cor varchar(230), disease float, 
disease_cor varchar(226), height float, height_cor varchar(230)
)
```

You could also define the type as `double precision` which is equivalent to `float(53)` or just `float` (as the default precision is 53).

You can check more about `float` data type on [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx).

Answer (score -1):

The syntax of the script of creating that table is correct, you would fail the semicolon at the end but it is not mandatory in all environments.